# Is this a good mobile redirection javascript? Or will I get banned from google?

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile, agent

I found this on the internet:

```
<script>//<![CDATA[    
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));    
var refUrl = document.referrer; // Get the URL where the user came from    
var prevUrl = refUrl.substr(7,23); // Create a substring after 'http://' and '.com'
var mobileUrl = "m.testsite.com"; // String from mobile site URL; must match prevUrl    
// Run auto-redirect only if the user is on mobile and isn't from m.testsite.com   
if ((mobile) && !(prevUrl == mobileUrl)) {        document.location = "http://m.testsite.com";    } //]]></script>
```

It works ok but I havnt seen this before and therefore im afraid that this could couse penalty or banning from google. What do you think? And should i put in mobile googlebot in the useragent strings?

Comment: no need for that cdata stuff unless you want to support browsers from 2000;)

Answer (score 0):

Google is very clever these days, it'll take more than a bad redirect to blacklist you. There's a good chance it'll know exactly what you're trying to do. Besides, they wouldn't ban you, unless you did something really, really bad. At worst, they wouldn't index that page.